# Does resetting and rebuilding EVs at level 100 (in Super Training) affect stats?

Tags: pokemon-sixth-generation

In previous generations, EVs only took effect upon level up, meaning that a level 100 Pokemon was stuck with the EVs you had previously trained it with.

With the edition of Super Training, and specifically, 'Reset Bags', you can re-spec your EVs at any time. But do these new EVs still only take effect upon level up?

Say I have a Gardevoir with mixed EVs on level 100, and I want to respec them into Special Attack & Speed for example, is this now possible? or will Resetting & Reapplying do nothing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Starting from Gen V, EVs are taken into account after every battle even when the Pokemon is at L100. And from my own experience with Super Training, those EVs are taken into account as they are gained, no need for leveling *or* a battle, so your L100 Gardevoir can be retrained through Super Training easily.

Comment: I think they're also recalculated immediately if you feed a Pokémon berries or vitamins.